# Connect bot to Azure bot service teams channel

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot) for creating a Teams bot, it says:

> If you installed your app but the bot isn't working, make sure the bot is [connected to the Azure Bot Service's Teams channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&preserve-view=true).

At that link, it says:

> To add the Microsoft Teams channel, open the bot in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/), click the Channels blade, and then click Teams.

In my Azure portal I don't see any bots or anything about Teams.  I'm really confused.  My bot does appear at https://dev.botframework.com/ and it's connected to the Teams channel there.  Is there something else I need to do to make it appear in the Azure portal?

Comment: Both are same. No need of any extra steps

Comment: Have you clicked the button to migrate to the Azure portal? Can you edit some screenshots into your question to show us what you're seeing in the Bot Framework portal? Also, have you made sure you're logging into the Azure portal and the Bot Framework portal with the same account? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @ElliottB - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I found the entire process very confusing and hard to use so I have moved on for now.  I will come back to this project when I have time.